# Express res.download() not actually downloading file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm attempting to return generated files to the front end through Express' res.download function. I'm using chrome, but whenever I call that API that executes the following code all that is returned is the same values returned from the Express res.sendFile() function.

I know that res.download uses res.sendFile, but I would like the download function to actually save to the file system instead of just returning the file in the body of the response.

This is my code.

```
exports.download = function(req,res) {
    var filePath = //somefile that I want to download
    res.download(filePath, 'response.txt', function(err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

I know that the above code at least partly works because I'm getting back, in the response, the contents of the file. However, I want it to be saved onto the file system.

Am I misunderstanding what the download function is supposed to do? Do I just need to take the response data and write it to the file system manually?

Comment: How are you making the request that hits the endpoint that calls this? The only way if will download is if the request is made via Chrome trying to open a new page. Making a request to this endpoint via XMLHttpRequest or something like that will not work.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I couldn't find why this is so. Can you explain?

Comment: When you click on a link, it is Chrome that is sending the request, and Chrome's default behavior is to download a file unless it is one that it can render. When you make the request from JS, your JS code is the thing that gets the response and is free to do whatever it wants with it, so Chrome's default behavior takes no part in it.

Answer (score 2):

`res.download` adds headers that suggest to the browser that the file should be downloaded rather than opened.  However, there's no way to force the browser to do this; it's ultimately the user's choice whether to download a particular file, typically.

If you're triggering this request with AJAX, well, that's not going to cause it to be downloaded, because your JavaScript is requesting that it get the data.

> Do I just need to take the response data and write it to the file system manually?

You don't have file system access in browser-side JavaScript.  I'm not sure how you intend to do this.

Comment: How would I trigger the request to cause it to be downloaded? A couple of months ago I had no issues accomplishing what I'm intending to do using this code. Now though it doesn't work.

Comment: @kkyrazis The answer to that is completely dependent on how the request is being triggered.  AJAX?  A popup?  Clicking on a link?